# jQuery cost counter giving strange output, using setInterval to loop an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I have a codepen which simply needs to have a counter where you count up pennies and pounds until the user clicks stop. The cost is calculated based on an hourly rate in the example (50).

Why am I getting strange issues whereby the counter resets at 3, when on animation complete I am updating the variable.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/QyydVB?editors=001

```
$(function(){

    var doc = $(document),
        rate = parseFloat(50 / 60 / 60).toFixed(4),
        earned = rate,
        paused = false;

    doc.on('click', '.js-start', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).text('Stop').removeClass('js-start').addClass('js-stop js-start--stop');

        setInterval(function(){

            if(!paused){

                var perSec = +earned + +rate;

                $({someValue: earned}).animate({someValue: perSec}, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    step: function() {
                        $('.js-count').text('£' + parseFloat(this.someValue).toFixed(2));
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        earned = parseFloat(+earned + +rate).toFixed(2);
                    }
                });

            }

        }, 1000);

    });

    doc.on('click', '.js-stop', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).text('Start').removeClass('js-stop js-start--stop').addClass('js-start');

        paused = true;

    });

});
```

Comment: I don't get the purpose of your animate method inside the interval. Anyway, this will go [out of sync](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) because of js being single thread language. Here anyway, your first animation starts after one second after first interval callback fires, and so completes after 3 seconds

Comment: I have the animate inside a setInterval as I don't know the total duration is it just counts up until the user hits stop. So if I remove the setInterval how can I loop the animation?